# ng-class not being applied

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I have a textarea containing a message to be posted and a span with the number of characters still available.

```
<textarea name="" cols="" rows="" maxLength="{{maxMessageLength}}" ng-model="messageText"/>
<div id="chatmessage-buttons">              
    <a ng-click="sendMessage()"><span>Invia</span></a>
<span ng-class="{message-length-alert: (messageText.length > messageLengthAlertTreshold), message-length: true}">{{maxMessageLength - messageText.length}}</span>
</div>
```

`messageText`, `maxMessageLength`and `messageLengthAlertTreshold`are all defined in the `$scope`, and the counter inside the span is updated correctly when I insert text in the textarea, changing the value of `messageText.length`.

However, neither the css class `message-length`nor `message-length-alert`are ever applied to my span, regardless of the value contained in `messageText`.

I also tried removing the check for `message-length-alert` leaving the ng-class attribute with just `{message-length: true}`, but it's not applied anyway.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Try to wrap the class name in quotes. Instead of:

```
ng-class="{message-length-alert: (messageText.length > messageLengthAlertTreshold), message-length: true}
```

Try:

```
ng-class="{'message-length-alert': (messageText.length > messageLengthAlertTreshold), 'message-length': true}
```

It is because the hash key must be a string or variable-like name.

Comment: You only need to wrap the class name in quotes if there is a hyphen in the class name. Otherwise you don't need this.